# Podman Installation for RHEL 8

Tags: linux, podman, containerd

I want to install Podman version 4.2.1 for RHEL 8 which is not available in UBI repo and in the source I cant not find any rpm.
https://github.com/containers/podman/releases/tag/v4.2.1
https://cdn-ubi.redhat.com/content/public/ubi/dist/ubi8/8/x86_64/appstream/os/Packages/p/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [here](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=podman), there should be plenty of RPMs available!

Comment: That's a great source. Thanks